# Ruby Error:No Method error..Undefined method invitation_type for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing an Ruby on Railssite...i am having a problem while redirecting to another form...i have done many things to fix it but i am not able to find out what is wrong in the code..anyone please help me to fix it ..please

**Error**

```
←[36m2014-04-23T05:46:13.280376+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m NoMethodError (undefined m
ethod `invitation_type' for nil:NilClass):
←[36m2014-04-23T05:46:13.280378+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/controllers/vectors_controller.rb in invited_new
```

**Code:**

```
    class VectorsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        ui = UserInvitation.where(hash_code: session[:hash_code]).first
        @vector = Vector.new(vector_params.merge({user_id: current_user.id, vector_type: ui.invitation_type}))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vector.save

        ui.completed_registration = true
        ui.save

        session[:hash_code] = nil
        flash[:notice] = "You're all set! Welcome to Availendar!"

        format.html {redirect_to vector_path(@vector.id)}
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Oops, looks like there's been a problem. Please correct it and try again."

        format.html {render action: :invited_new}
      end
    end
  end


  def invited_new
    @user_invitation = UserInvitation.where(hash_code: session[:hash_code]).first
    #raise ArgumentError "Cannot find invitation with hash_code #{session[:hash_code]}" unless @user_invitation.present?

    @vector = Vector.new(user: current_user, vector_type: @user_invitation.invitation_type)
    @vector.build_address
  end
 ////create action///
```

def create
    ui = UserInvitation.where(hash_code: session[:hash_code]).first
    @vector = Vector.new(vector_params.merge({user_id: current_user.id, vendor_type: ui.invitation_type}))
    respond_to do |format|
      if @vector.save
        ui.completed_registration = true
        ui.save
        session[:hash_code] = nil
        format.html {redirect_to vector_path(@vector.id)}
      else
        format.html {render action: :invited_new}
      end
    end
  end

Comment: You commented this line `#raise ArgumentError "Cannot find invitation with hash_code #{session[:hash_code]}" unless @user_invitation.present?`.you did it mistakenly or you wanted it to be like that?

Comment: the problem seems to be in the invited_new action's user_invitation.invitation_type method/attribute call, because invitation_type seems to be nil. Like you said, I think it is useful to check that out. Or even better like RSB pointed out check the whole user_invitation object.

Comment: Your `@user_invitation` returned nil, but you explicitly tried to access its `invitation_type` when doing `Vector.new` even if it's nil.

Comment: The problem is that `@user_invitation` is nil and not `invitation_type` is nil. The error raised is, no method `invitation_type` for nil class. Here nil class being `@user_invitation`.

Comment: Firstly to be clear do you have this line `unless @user_invitation.present?` in the commented of your original code?

Comment: no just i have commented the unless line..still error occurs

Answer (score 3):

In your `invited_new` action `@user_invitation` is coming blank due to which it is showing this error, here's the solution

```
  def invited_new
    @user_invitation = UserInvitation.where(hash_code: session[:hash_code]).first

    unless @user_invitation.blank?    
      @vector = Vector.new(user: current_user, vector_type: @user_invitation.invitation_type)
      @vector.build_address
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `unless` for `if`, so is the error

change this line

```
unless @user_invitation.present? #=> false
```

to

```
if @user_invitation.present? #=> true



def invited_new
    @user_invitation = UserInvitation.where(hash_code: session[:hash_code]).first

    if @user_invitation.present?

    @vector = Vector.new(user: current_user, vector_type: @user_invitation.invitation_type)
    @vector.build_address
  end
```

Comment: pavan i used your code..now i am getting same error for create action now..undefined method invitation_type .. app[web.1]:←[0m NoMethodError (undefined m ethod invitation_type' for nil:NilClass): ←[33m2014-04-23T06:31:55.447060+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m app/controllers/vectors_ controller.rb:32:in create......can u please help..

Comment: in create action..i have updated the create action code..please review it.Thanks

Comment: @ganesh Try posting the updated code in your post,not in my post.

Comment: sorry i wrongly did it..in question i have updated the code..please check

Answer (score 1):

OK, lets try to break it down step by step:

**Problem**

- Sometimes this line might return blank array (nothing found)

  ```
  UserInvitation.where(hash_code: session[:hash_code])
  ```
- Which means, this will be `nil` (first of blank array is nil, right !)

  ```
  @user_invitation = UserInvitation.where(hash_code: session[:hash_code]).first
  ```
- Now, it makes sense this throws (Undefined method `invitation_type` for nil:NilClass)

  ```
  @user_invitation.invitation_type
  ```

**Solution**

Instead, use **[try](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try)** which as the name indicates will try to get the attribute or and simply returns `nil` when called on a `nil` object, so your method should look like this:

```
class VectorsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    ui = UserInvitation.where(hash_code: session[:hash_code]).first
    @vector = Vector.new(vector_params.merge({user_id: current_user.id, vector_type: ui.try(:invitation_type)}))

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vector.save
        ui.completed_registration = true
        ui.save
        session[:hash_code] = nil
        flash[:notice] = "You're all set! Welcome to Availendar!"
        format.html {redirect_to vector_path(@vector.id)}
      else
        flash[:alert] = "Oops, looks like there's been a problem. Please correct it and try again."
        format.html {render action: :invited_new}
      end
    end
  end

  def invited_new
    @user_invitation = UserInvitation.where(hash_code: session[:hash_code]).first
    #raise ArgumentError "Cannot find invitation with hash_code #{session[:hash_code]}" unless @user_invitation.present?

    @vector = Vector.new(user: current_user, vector_type: @user_invitation.try(:invitation_type))
    @vector.build_address
  end
end
```

Comment: Nimir i tried using your code but after invited_new action ..i am getting error for create_action ...←[33m2014-04-23T06:31:55.447058+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m NoMethodError (undefined m
ethod `invitation_type' for nil:NilClass):
←[33m2014-04-23T06:31:55.447060+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   app/controllers/vectors_
controller.rb:32:in `create'

Comment: you need to do the same workaround in `create` action for `ui.try(:invitation_type)`

Comment: the method error has gone now..but still the form is not saving...shows errors as in form validation..what could be the reason? 
    Vendor type can't be blank
    Vendor type is an invalid vendor type

Comment: you should have seen this coming, since `invitation_type` will be `nil` so either shut down the validation on Vendor type or provide some default value ... it really depends on your business requirements here

Comment: actually the code is working and the invitation type is also set when i remove this line its working 
  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}...i replaced with 
  devise_for :users..Now the invitation type is set but the other forms wont redirect as i have written signup path in registration controller...is there any way to fix it so everything works?

Comment: class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 
  private

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
   #'/planners/invited_new'
     if resource.planner_type == "planner" 
      '/path1/invited_new'
      elsif resource.planner_type == "bride"
      '/path2/invited_new'
     else
      '/path3/invited_new'

      end
  end
  
end

Comment: Its considered bad practice in SO to ask new questions inside questions and specially in comments , please open a new question so me and other community members get to help you better